# Is there an integer equivalent of __toString()

Tags: php

Is there a way to tell PHP how to convert your objects to ints? Ideally it would look something like

```
class ExampleClass
{
    ...

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }

    public function __toInt()
    {
        return $this->getId();
    }
}
```

I realize it's not supported in this exact form, but is there an easy (not-so-hacky) workaround?

---------------------- EDIT EDIT EDIT -----------------------------

Thanks everybody! The main reason I'm looking into this is I'd like to make some classes (form generators, menu classes etc) use objects instead of arrays(uniqueId => description). This is easy enough if you decide they should work only with those objects, or only with objects that extend some kind of generic object superclass.

But I'm trying to see if there's a middle road: ideally my framework classes could accept either integer-string pairs, or objects with getId() and getDescription() methods. Because this is something that must have occurred to someone else before I'd like to use the combined knowledge of stackoverflow to find out if there's a standard / best-practice way of doing this **that doesn't clash with the php standard library, common frameworks etc**.

Comment: I'm not sure how PHP would know the difference? __toString() is used when an object is directly output, not just typecast.

Comment: You could do a "Object" class, like in Java, and have everything derived from it, then implement an overridable method.

Comment: @Phil Luckily I'm using 5.3 so I no longer have that problem :) http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring

Comment: There is no such equivalent built-in, but there are plenty of ways to get at an INT in a somewhat automatic way. Could you describe the usage you have that is motivating your search for this? Maybe we can help you think of a different way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: A possible scenario is comparing an object to an int:  if ($myPseudoInt > 1) - which result in a notice a la: "Object of class PseudoInt could not be converted to int". Would have been nifty with a __toInt()-method to allow such comparison without explicit castings.

Comment: We are still waiting for this, but maybe one day: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/object_cast_to_types

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no such thing. I'm not exactly sure what the reason is you need this, but consider the following options:

Adding a `toInt()` method, casting in the class. You're probably aware of this already.

```
public function toInt()
{
    return (int) $this->__toString();
}
```

Double casting outside the class, will result in an int.

```
$int = (int) (string) $class;
```

Make a special function outside the class:

```
function intify($class)
{
    return (int) (string) $class;
}
$int = intify($class);
```

Of course the `__toString()` method can return a string with a number in it: `return '123'`. Usage outside the class might auto-cast this string to an integer.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I'm looking into this is I'd like to make some classes (form generators, menu classes etc) use objects instead of arrays(uniqueId => description) but without adapting them to those objects specifically (loss of generality) or without introducing an overarching Object class (loss of generality + lots of code that needs to be adapted).

I'm hoping there's some kind of intermediary solution to be found.

Comment: That is where interfaces are for, right? spl_object_hash() returns a unique id for every object. Good question, though.

Comment: Sweet! But those ids would change from request to request, no?

Comment: `spl_object_hash()` returns a random hash every new request.

Answer (score 3):

Make your objects implement ArrayAccess and Iterator.

```
class myObj implements ArrayAccess, Iterator
{
}

$thing = new myObj();
$thing[$id] = $name;
```

Then, in the code that consumes this data, you can use the same "old style" array code that you had before:

```
// Here, $thing can be either an array or an instance of myObj
function doSomething($thing) {
    foreach ($thing as $id => $name) {
        // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use retyping:

```
class Num
{
    private $num;

    public function __construct($num)
    {
        $this->num = $num;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->num;
    }
}

$n1 = new Num(5);
$n2 = new Num(10);

$n3 = (int) (string) $n1 + (int) (string) $n2; // 15
```

Answer (score 0):

`__toString()` exists as a magic method.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring

`__toInt()` does not.

Comment: I think you misread the question ;) *Is there an **integer equivalent** of `__toString()`*

Comment: @Felix, I did misread it, and I edited my answer seconds before you replied :) Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks for your time! I know __toInt() doesn't exist, that's why I'm asking for a workaround.

Comment: This seems like almost the correct answer, perhaps it should say "neither `__toInt()` nor `__toInteger()` nor anything like it exists".

Comment: I think this is a better answer for the non-OP audience/viewers.