# PHP object converted to int

Tags: php

I have the following that produces error of "Object of class cField could not be converted to int in :\notesinfo.php
For troubleshooting, I have placed the `&& $this->trans_id > 0 ){` on it's own row and that is the row indicated in the error.

```
//Red row
elseif ($this->followup_date->CurrentValue < date('m/d/Y')
&& $this->trans_id > 0 ){
    $this->RowAttrs["style"] = "background-color:#fe1f1f";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to `var_dump($this->trans_id)`? I suppose it is an object. So PHP cannot guess what value should be taken from that object to compare with 0.

Comment: Can you provide some more code?

Comment: Notice: Object of class cField could not be converted to int in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\notesinfo.php on line 1173
object(cField)#4 (85) { ["TblName"]=> string(5) "notes" ["TblVar"]=> string(5) "notes" ["FldName"]=> string(8) "trans_id"

Comment: have you tried to debug/checking this code `$this->followup_date->CurrentValue < date('m/d/Y')` ? may be this condition is not working as you are expecting.

Comment: This is for a row where the trans_id is 606   It does appear that the value is being seen as string.

 ["TblVar"]=> string(5) "notes" ["FldName"]=> string(8) "trans_id" ["FldVar"]=> s ["CurrentValue"]=> string(3) "606" ["ViewValue"]=> string(3) "606" ["EditValue"]=> NULL ["HrefValue2"]=> NULL ["FormValue"]=> NULL ["QueryStringValue"]=> string(3) "606" ["DbValue"]=> string(3) "606" ["Sortable"]=> bool(true) ["UploadPath"]=> string(0) "" ["OldUploadPath"]=> string(0) "" ["HrefPath"]=> string(0) ""

Comment: @macunte did you solve your problem ?

Comment: No, I'm not quite sure how to implement the code Armin suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reconstruct your issue, with this example:

```
<?php

class MyValue
{
    private $value = 42;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string) $this->value;
    }
}

$instance = new MyValue();

if ((int) (string) $instance === 42) {
    var_dump('Here we go');
}
```

To make it work, I've added the `__toString` method. When I compare the object with a number, I cast it first to string and then to integer.

Here is also another post, which had the same question: [Is there an integer equivalent of __toString()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3751363/is-there-an-integer-equivalent-of-tostring)

Comment: Thank you but I'm not quite sure how I place your recommendation into my code.

Comment: You add a __toString method to the class cField  and modify the call in else if like described.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up simply replacing

$this->trans_id > 0

with

$this->trans_id->CurrentValue > 0

and solved.